# My javascript bot stops music before the end

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

[This is my code](https://pastebin.com/F0bhBU1L)

And below is the part that I suspect is wrong:

```js
const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))
    .on('end', () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on('error', error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more information to your question, for example your reasoning as to why you believe that code block is wrong, any console.log errors that could be useful, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
The solution is in this thread: https://github.com/amishshah/ytdl-core-discord/issues/6
What you need to do is change

```
const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))
```

To

```
const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url, {highWaterMark: 1<<25}))
```